# windows phone page XAML Preview not showing in Blend and Visual studio

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, blend, win-universal-app

I have written code in mainpage.xaml in universal app project and windows phone 8.1 section. The **preview in visual studio and blend is showing as empty**. Pictures are attached.
NO TEXT of text block set from back c# code. all code is set here.
Windows phone ouput is also attached.
Following is the code

```
<Page 
x:Class="PakistanNewspapers.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:PakistanNewspapers"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Hub>
    <Hub.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblHeader" Text="Pakistani Newspapers"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Hub.HeaderTemplate>
<HubSection Header="Urdu Newspapers" >
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <Image x:Name="txtNewspaperImage" Height="60" Width="60" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtNewspaperHeader" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="14.667" FontWeight="Light" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtNewsHeader" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="14.667" FontWeight="Light" Width="200" MaxHeight="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                </StackPanel>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>

            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</HubSection>

<HubSection Header="English Newspapers"/>

<HubSection Header="About"/>
</Hub>
```

While the preview in visual studio and blend is showing as :
[image: Visual Studio]
[image: Blend]
[image: Windows Phone]

Comment: Try using [sample design data as seen in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn169081.aspx).

Comment: @sibbl the link shows the data for MVVM. i will look into it. but at least the hub header has no bind only text displayed. why its not showing ?

Comment: do you have any code in your code behind that is perhaps executing at design time? if it crashes because it's expecting to be at runtime it might cause the designer to fail. try disabling all the code behind and if the frontend loads, find a way to defer it so that it only loads at runtime